# Asp.net networking/restclient layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have been working on creating maintainable networking layer for our Asp.Net Core Web Api project. Right now I have created Generic methods for *Get, Post, Put* like this.

```
 public class BaseClient
{
    private HttpClient _client;
    private ILogger<BaseClient> _logger;
    private string AuthToken;
    public BaseClient(HttpClient client, ILogger<BaseClient> logger, AuthenticationHeader authHeader)
    {
        _client = client;
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("url/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        _logger = logger;
        AuthToken = authHeader.AuthHeader;
    }
    public async Task<FailureResponseModel> GetFailureResponseModel(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        FailureResponseModel failureModel = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<FailureResponseModel>();
        failureModel.ResponseStatusCode = Convert.ToInt32(response.StatusCode);
        _logger.LogError("Request Failed: {Error}", failureModel.ResultDetails);
        return failureModel;
    }

    public async Task<object> ProcessAsync<T>(HttpRequestMessage request, NamingStrategy namingStrategy)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AuthToken))
        {
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AuthToken);
        }
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Request Succeeded");
            var dezerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
                {
                    NamingStrategy = namingStrategy
                }
            };
            T responseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(), dezerializerSettings);
            return responseModel;
        }
        else
        {
            return await GetFailureResponseModel(response);

        }
    }
    public async Task<object> GetAsync<T>(string uri)
    {
        return await GetAsync<T>(uri, new DefaultNamingStrategy());
    }
    public async Task<object> GetAsync<T>(string uri, NamingStrategy namingStrategy)
    {
        using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri))
        {
            return await ProcessAsync<T>(requestMessage, namingStrategy);
        }
    }
    public async Task<object> PostAsync<T1, T2>(string uri, T2 content)
    {
        return await PostAsync<T1, T2>(uri, content, new DefaultNamingStrategy());
    }
    public async Task<object> PostAsync<T1, T2>(string uri, T2 content, NamingStrategy namingStrategy)
    {
        using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri))
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
            using (var stringContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
            {
                requestMessage.Content = stringContent;
                return await ProcessAsync<T1>(requestMessage, namingStrategy);
            }
        }
    }
    public async Task<object> PutAsyc<T1, T2>(string uri, T2 content)
    {
        return await PutAsyc<T1, T2>(uri, content, new DefaultNamingStrategy());
    }
    public async Task<object> PutAsyc<T1, T2>(string uri, T2 content, NamingStrategy namingStrategy)
    {
        using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, uri))
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content,
                    Formatting.None,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                    });
            using (var stringContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
            {
                requestMessage.Content = stringContent;
                return await ProcessAsync<T1>(requestMessage, namingStrategy);
            }
        }
    }
```

As it can be seen I have to write 2 Methods for Get, Post and Put due to SnakeCase and CamelCase Naming Strategies as some response consist of **SnakeCase** and some responses are in **CamelCase**

I have created ApiManager kinda class which calls above Class methods like this.

```
 public class ClubMatasClient
    {
        private BaseClient _client;
        private ILogger<ClubMatasClient> _logger;
        private string AuthToken;
        public ClubMatasClient(BaseClient client, ILogger<ClubMatasClient> logger, AuthenticationHeader authHeader)
        {
            _client = client;
            _logger = logger;
            AuthToken = authHeader.AuthHeader;
        }

        public async Task<object> GetShops(string category)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("ClubMatas outgoing request: {RequestName}", nameof(GetShops));
            return await _client.GetAsync<ShopsResponseModel>($"v2/shops?category={WebUtility.UrlEncode(category)}");
        }
        public async Task<object> PostLogin(LoginRequestModel form)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("ClubMatas outgoing request: {RequestName}", nameof(PostLogin));
            return await _client.PostAsync<LoginResponseModel, LoginRequestModel>("v2/login", form, new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy());
        }
}
```

And this class in being injected in my Controllers and I am using this ApiManager like this to call api and return response.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult<object>> GetShops([FromQuery(Name = "category")]string category)
    {
        var response = await _httpClient.GetShops(category);
        return ParseResponse<ShopsResponseModel>(response);
    }
```

**ParseResponse** is helper Generic method which either return SuccessModel (passed as T) or failure response Model.

```
 protected ActionResult<object> ParseResponse<T>(object response)
    {
        if (response.GetType() == typeof(T))
        {
            return Ok(response);
        }
        else
        {
            return Error(response);
        }
    }
```

Now my question is as I am fairly new to C#/ASP.net Core , is my current flow/architecture is fine, and how can I make it more elegant and more flexible.

Comment: I suggest that you look into the [IHttpClientFactory interface](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2); it was designed to accomplish exactly what you're doing here but has more features and is maintained by Microsoft =D.

Comment: Well I am using the same the only difference is i am using TypedClient

Comment: Ah sorry, the `BaseClient` class threw me off; give me some time and I'll supply a proper refactor as an answer.

Comment: You have a typo _PutAsyc_ (I think)

Answer (score 2):

I thought that what you have is actually quite solid; my only suggestion is that you should take advantage of C#'s features in order to slightly clean things up. First, let's create an options object to hold the various items that you're injecting into the class:

```
public class HttpServiceOptions<TLogger>
{
    public string AuthenticationToken { get; set; }
    public ILogger<TLogger> Logger { get; set; }
}
```

This should make it much simpler to add/remove dependencies to the "system" since everything is injected via a single "container". Now, let's make your base class abstract and refactor it to accept our options object:

```
public abstract class AbstractHttpService<TLogger>
{
    private readonly string _authToken;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public ILogger<TLogger> Logger { get; }

    public AbstractHttpService(HttpClient httpClient, IOptions<HttpServiceOptions<TLogger>> options) {
        var optionsValue = options.Value;
        var client = httpClient;

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("url/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

        _authToken = optionsValue.AuthenticationToken;
        _client = client;

        Logger = optionsValue.Logger;
    }

    public async Task<FailureResponseModel> GetFailureResponseModel(HttpResponseMessage response) {
        var failureModel = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<FailureResponseModel>();

        failureModel.ResponseStatusCode = Convert.ToInt32(response.StatusCode);

        Logger.LogError("Request Failed: {Error}", failureModel.ResultDetails);

        return failureModel;
    }
    public async Task<object> ProcessAsync<T>(HttpRequestMessage request, NamingStrategy namingStrategy) {
        var authToken = _authToken;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authToken)) {
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authToken);
        }

        var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            Logger.LogInformation("Request Succeeded");

            var dezerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
                ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver {
                    NamingStrategy = namingStrategy
                }
            };
            var responseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(), dezerializerSettings);

            return responseModel;
        }
        else {
            return await GetFailureResponseModel(response);
        }
    }
    public async Task<object> GetAsync<T>(string uri) {
        return await GetAsync<T>(uri, new DefaultNamingStrategy());
    }
    public async Task<object> GetAsync<T>(string uri, NamingStrategy namingStrategy) {
        using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri)) {
            return await ProcessAsync<T>(requestMessage, namingStrategy);
        }
    }
    public async Task<object> PostAsync<T1, T2>(string uri, T2 content) {
        return await PostAsync<T1, T2>(uri, content, new DefaultNamingStrategy());
    }
    public async Task<object> PostAsync<T1, T2>(string uri, T2 content, NamingStrategy namingStrategy) {
        using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri)) {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);

            using (var stringContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")) {
                requestMessage.Content = stringContent;
                return await ProcessAsync<T1>(requestMessage, namingStrategy);
            }
        }
    }
    public async Task<object> PutAsyc<T1, T2>(string uri, T2 content) {
        return await PutAsyc<T1, T2>(uri, content, new DefaultNamingStrategy());
    }
    public async Task<object> PutAsyc<T1, T2>(string uri, T2 content, NamingStrategy namingStrategy) {
        using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, uri)) {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                value: content,
                formatting: Formatting.None,
                settings: new JsonSerializerSettings {
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                }
            );

            using (var stringContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")) {
                requestMessage.Content = stringContent;

                return await ProcessAsync<T1>(requestMessage, namingStrategy);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We also need to implement the `ClubMatasHttpService` by deriving from the abstract class:

```
public sealed class ClubMatasHttpService : AbstractHttpService<ClubMatasHttpService>
{
    public ClubMatasHttpService(HttpClient httpClient, IOptions<HttpServiceOptions<ClubMatasHttpService>> options) : base(httpClient, options) { }

    public async Task<object> GetShops(string category) {
        Logger.LogInformation("ClubMatas outgoing request: {RequestName}", nameof(GetShops));

        return await GetAsync<ShopsResponseModel>($"v2/shops?category={WebUtility.UrlEncode(category)}");
    }
    public async Task<object> PostLogin(LoginRequestModel form) {
        Logger.LogInformation("ClubMatas outgoing request: {RequestName}", nameof(PostLogin));

        return await PostAsync<LoginResponseModel, LoginRequestModel>("v2/login", form, new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy());
    }
}
```

Finally, we write a couple of extension methods to help configure everything:

```
public static class IServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IHttpClientBuilder AddClubMatasHttpService(this IServiceCollection services, Action<HttpServiceOptions<ClubMatasHttpService>> configureOptions) {
        if (null == services) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services)); }
        if (null == configureOptions) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configureOptions)); }

        services.Configure(configureOptions);

        return services.AddHttpClient<ClubMatasHttpService>();
    }
    public static IHttpClientBuilder AddClubMatasHttpService(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration) {
        return services.AddClubMatasHttpService(configuration.Bind);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it really cleanup stuff :) Just one question which is really bugging me, you can as i am expecting 2 different models in case of success and failure, i am setting return type as `object`. Is there any other elegant way to fix this?

Comment: @Shabirjan I think we can, once I finish up some actual work here I'll play around with the code a bit more and see what happens.

Comment: Sure and thanks again :) waiting to hear from you soon

Comment: A question how would I register and inject dependencies by using that options class?

Comment: @Shabirjan Sorry for the delay, busy with other things but I promise I will get back to ya on that; in addition to the generic stuffs.

Comment: @Shabirjan I have updated my answer so that configuration is handled through ASP.NET's DI system and added some extensions that demo possible usage.